# CMake finds Boost but Boost_INCLUDE_DIR is not set

Tags: boost, cmake, centos

I'm trying to build a CMake project on CentOS 5 using a built-from-source version of Boost. I have installed Boost 1.74.0 in `/tmp/boost/boost_1_74_0`. In my `CMakeLists.txt` I try to find this installation with `find_package(Boost 1.72 REQUIRED COMPONENTS graph)`. I also pass `-DBOOST_ROOT=/tmp/boost/boost_1_74_0` to `cmake`.

The call to `find_package` ostensibly succeeds. However, `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR` is subsequently still set to `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND`. I do not understand why or how this happens, the project builds on several other systems on which I have installed Boost via a package manager. Even when I symlink or copy `/tmp/boost/boost_1_74_0/boost` to `/usr/include`, CMake is still unable to set `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR`. What could be the issue here?

Here's what CMake outputs when I also specify `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON`:

```
-- Finding boost...                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
-- Found Boost 1.74.0 at /usr/lib/cmake/Boost-1.74.0                                                                                                                                                                                         
--   Requested configuration: QUIET REQUIRED COMPONENTS graph                                                                                                                                                                                
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_headers 1.74.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS /usr/lib/cmake)                                                                                                                                          
-- Found boost_headers 1.74.0 at /usr/lib/cmake/boost_headers-1.74.0                                                                                                                                                                         
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_graph 1.74.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS /usr/lib/cmake)                                                                                                                                            
-- Found boost_graph 1.74.0 at /usr/lib/cmake/boost_graph-1.74.0                                                                                                                                                                             
-- Boost toolset is gcc8 (GNU 8.3.1)                                                                                                                                                                                                         
-- Scanning /usr/lib/cmake/boost_graph-1.74.0/libboost_graph-variant*.cmake                                                                                                                                                                  
--   Including /usr/lib/cmake/boost_graph-1.74.0/libboost_graph-variant-shared.cmake                                                                                                                                                         
--   [x] libboost_graph.so.1.74.0                                                                                                                                                                                                            
--   Including /usr/lib/cmake/boost_graph-1.74.0/libboost_graph-variant-static.cmake                                                                                                                                                         
--   [ ] libboost_graph.a                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
-- Adding boost_graph dependencies: regexheaders                                                                                                                                                                                             
-- Found boost_regex 1.74.0 at /usr/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.74.0                                                                                                                                                                             
-- Boost toolset is gcc8 (GNU 8.3.1)                                                                                                                                                                                                         
-- Scanning /usr/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.74.0/libboost_regex-variant*.cmake                                                                                                                                                                  
--   Including /usr/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.74.0/libboost_regex-variant-shared.cmake                                                                                                                                                         
--   [x] libboost_regex.so.1.74.0                                                                                                                                                                                                            
--   Including /usr/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.74.0/libboost_regex-variant-static.cmake                                                                                                                                                         
--   [ ] libboost_regex.a
-- Adding boost_regex dependencies: headers
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Boost_INCLUDE_DIR` is a variable that can be specified as input to the FindBoost.cmake module to lookup a Boost installation. You are more likely to be interested in `Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable (note the trailing `S`) that is populated by the FindBoost.cmake module. See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) for further information.

Comment: That explains it. I wonder why if works on other systems though.